# How to jump to definition for a file in node_modules from VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the following file open in Visual Studio Code:

```css
@import "~normalize.css/normalize.css";
@import "./fonts.css";
body {
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}
```

I want to be able to navigate from there to the CSS files imported. I assumed I should use something like Cmd/Ctrl+Click but that doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: related issue - https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/issues/136

Answer (score 5):

This [VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrluje.vscode-goto-node-modules) will provide the functionality you're looking for.

Once installed, just use F12 to open the source.